# How to create a new field for mongodb just like new attributes in SQL

Tags: mongodb

i'm trying to learn `MongoDB`. i have created a `Collection` with `Compass`, but I don't know how to add indexes and fields like `name`, `gender` ..etc, to the created collection.

If anyone could help me , I would really appreciate it.

Comment: please post your code, and what you've tried, what language are you using

Answer (score 0):

It would help to know what context you are using MongoDB in.

You need to [model](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/) the data by creating a schema which defines the properties of the documents in your collection.

Here's a quick example using Express and mongoose:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    text: String,
    author: {
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
        },
        username: String
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    },
    likes: [
    {
      user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User"
      }
    }
  ]
});



module.exports = mongoose.model("Comment", commentSchema);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But I don't use any back-end because I have an assignment to use MongoDB to import data. I think my problem has been solved.